# proportionaly find values between 2 numbers

Tags: excel, interpolation

Need a bit of help here please, on probably simple thing.

How do I find numbers in column B between B1 (330) and B6 (260) for values in A?

```
     A          B

1   0.35     330
2   0.36        
3   0.37        
4   0.38        
5   0.39    
6   0.4      260
```

I need calculate B proportional based on values in A. need to find what values will be from B2 - B5 It's something like if 0.35 = 330 and 0.4 = 260 what will be 0.37?

Comment: please elaborate a bit more; eg. do you know the relation between A and B or do you need to calculate B inversely proportional to A based on the given values?

Comment: Yes, I need calculate B proportional based on values in A. need to find what values will be from B2 - B5 

It's something like if 0.35 = 330 and 0.4 = 260 what will be 0.37?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a linear interpolation.  First we will get the equation for the line from the two outside points:

```
Equation: y = m * x + b
m: =SLOPE(y,x)
b: =INTERCEPT(y,x)
```

[image]

and then we apply the equation to the intermediary points.  So in **B2** enter:

```
=A2*$F$1+$F$2
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: x, y axis very nice, ty very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

- added a third ***`C`*** column with formula

  ```
  =(A2-$A$1)/($A$6-$A$1)
  ```
- column ***`B`*** then contains:

  ```
  =$B$1+($B$6-$B$1)*C4
  ```

[image]